# NullReferenceException в алгоритме AStars

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, null, unity3d

Я пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм AStars для своей игры. Суть алгоритма заключаетсяв поиске пути по графу

Граф я создал, но теперь я не могу подключить сам алгоритм

Это класс Astars. Есть ещё класс Node, но там ничего такого, просто конструктор и набор параметров для каждой из вершин

```
public class Astar
{
    List<List<Node>> Grid;  //нужно для алгоритма. Это просто разметка карты на вершины графа
    int GridRows
    {
        get
        {
           return Grid[0].Count;
        }
    }
    int GridCols
    {
        get
        {
            return Grid.Count;
        }
    }

    public Astar(List<List<Node>> grid)   //конструктор 
    {
        Grid = grid;
    }

    public Stack<Node> FindPath(Vector2 Start, Vector2 End) //сам алгоритм поиска пути
    {
        Node start = new Node(new Vector2((int)(Start.x/Node.NODE_SIZE), (int) (Start.y/Node.NODE_SIZE)), true);
        Node end = new Node(new Vector2((int)(End.x / Node.NODE_SIZE), (int)(End.y / Node.NODE_SIZE)), true);

        Stack<Node> Path = new Stack<Node>();
        List<Node> OpenList = new List<Node>();
        List<Node> ClosedList = new List<Node>();
        List<Node> adjacencies;
        Node current = start;
       
        // add start node to Open List
        OpenList.Add(start);

        while(OpenList.Count != 0 && !ClosedList.Exists(x => x.Position == end.Position))
        {
            current = OpenList[0];
            OpenList.Remove(current);
            ClosedList.Add(current);
            adjacencies = GetAdjacentNodes(current);


            foreach(Node n in adjacencies)
            {
                if (!ClosedList.Contains(n) && n.Walkable)
                {
                    if (!OpenList.Contains(n))
                    {
                        n.Parent = current;
                        n.DistanceToTarget = Math.Abs(n.Position.x - end.Position.x) + Math.Abs(n.Position.y - end.Position.y);
                        n.Cost = n.Weight + n.Parent.Cost;
                        OpenList.Add(n);
                        OpenList = OpenList.OrderBy(node => node.F).ToList<Node>();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        // construct path, if end was not closed return null
        if(!ClosedList.Exists(x => x.Position == end.Position))
        {
            return null;
        }

        // if all good, return path
        Node temp = ClosedList[ClosedList.IndexOf(current)];
        if (temp == null) return null;
        do
        {
            Path.Push(temp);
            temp = temp.Parent;
        } while (temp != start && temp != null) ;
        return Path;
    }
    
    private List<Node> GetAdjacentNodes(Node n)
    {
        List<Node> temp = new List<Node>();

        int row = (int)n.Position.y;
        int col = (int)n.Position.x;

        if(row + 1 < GridRows)
        {
            temp.Add(Grid[col][row + 1]);
        }
        if(row - 1 >= 0)
        {
            temp.Add(Grid[col][row - 1]);
        }
        if(col - 1 >= 0)
        {
            temp.Add(Grid[col - 1][row]);
        }
        if(col + 1 < GridCols)
        {
            temp.Add(Grid[col + 1][row]);
        }

        return temp;
    }
}
```

И есть скрипт для моего юнита

```
public class warrior : MonoBehaviour
{
Astar astar; //создаю объект класса Astar, чтобы потом вызывать FindPath

private navigationSquare square;      //это нужно для нахождения конечной точки
public GameObject grid;               //на этом объекте висит скрипт navigationSquare
Stack<Node> path = new Stack<Node>(); //стек с путем, который вернет функция astar.FindPath(...);


void Start()
{
    square = grid.GetComponent<navigationSquare>(); //получаю доступ к скрипту
    Debug.Log(square.end.x);
    astar = new Astar(makeGrid.getGraph());         //инициализирую объект при помощи конструктора
                                                    //makeGrid.getGraph() вернет List<List<Node>> карту графов
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(square.canGo == true){
        Vector2 pos_start = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y); //начальная позиция юнита
        Vector2 pos_end = new Vector2(square.end.x, square.end.y);                   //и место, куда он должен придти
        path = astar.FindPath(pos_start, pos_end); 
        printPath(); //её реализация не важна   
    }
    
    
}
}
```

в итоге я получаю вот такой error [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я так понимаю, что у меня ошибка в том, что я как-то неправильно создаю объект класса Astar или что я неправильно вызываю его методы

Уже несколько дней ломаю голову над этими NullReferenceException....

Научите неразумного, добрые люди(

102 строка `adjacencies = GetAdjacentNodes(current);`
145 строка `if(row + 1 < GridRows)`
29 строка `path = astar.FindPath(pos_start, pos_end);`

Comment: Подсказка `OpenList.OrderBy` - здесь с помощью `Linq` вы пересоздаете список, это медленно и кушает память, попробуйте вместо этого использовать метод `List.Sort()`. Это не решит вашу проблему, но улучшит производительность кода. По поводу `null` - все просто, метод `GetAdjacentNodes` получает `null` на вход в качестве аргумента, и при попытке обратиться к этому `null` (`n.Position`), вы получаете искомое исключение.

Comment: А, `GridRows`, ну тогда возможно скрипт выполняется до того как вы создали поле, попробуйте защитить геттеры `return Grid[0].Count;` замените на `return GridCols > 0 ? Grid[0]?.Count ?? 0 : 0;`, а `return Grid.Count;` на `return Grid?.Count ?? 0;`